# Error when compiling c-graphics in a Turbo C++ program

Tags: c, graphics

In my Turbo C++ program, I can't run any of the graphics program. When it compiles, it shows an error like:

```
undefined symbol _line, _closegraph,_ getmaxx etc...
```

Is it due to the settings of my c-program?

Comment: and exactly why this question gets a negative?

Comment: I think some people saw TC++ and thought this question was an ill fated attempt at humor, it seems to be serious.

Answer (score 3):

Is this an old program that was written for Turbo C++, and that you're trying to compile with a modern compiler? If so, it might be the case that the program uses compiler-specific extensions and libraries, that are simply not available in the compiler you're using now.

If that is the case, you must either

- find an existing library for your current environment that emulates the old Turbo C++ one, or
- find out exactly what each call is supposed to do, and change the code to use something that your environment supports.

Answer (score 1):

It's compile error and not link error. Looks like "graphics.h" is missing.

Do

```
#include "graphics.h"
```

Comment: The question clearly says 'when i tried to compile'. In turbo c++ compiler, it does not list link errors pertaining to missing library during compile-time. So I said missing headerfile. Whats wrong with that? And why negative?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are typical of a missing library in your build. Try linking the appropriate libraries and rebuild the solution (most likely graphics.lib).

-John

Comment: How are so sure that it's not missing headerfile, i.e. not a compile error but a linker error?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is of compiling error then you may add the header file:

```
#include<graphics.h>
```

if the problem still persists then make sure you have added the header file:

```
#include<dos.h>
```